# 2.9.X Theme to for 2.76b... our lab pc can't run version upper from 2.76b

Tags: video, theme, documentation

2.9.X Theme to for 2.76b... our lab pc can't run version upper from 2.76b ...

i am teacher and i want teach blender to our student
our lab is old becouse we in thired world country (poor country)

i check every version and seem the 2.76b i called blender for poor's
it's only upper version work in that pc's

but i want theme to look 2.76b like  new 2.9 blender

is this possible

and from where i get manual and tutorial for 2.76b exactly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [2.8 theme from Blendswap](https://www.blendswap.com/blend/21909)
Here is a [2.8 theme from Blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/heres-blender-2-8-theme-for-blender-2-7/1125705)

Please keep in mind that Blender 2.8+ also has a new Collection system (instead of layers) - which can't be changed using a theme.

Good luck :-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks For Replay ... seem 2.8 and 2.9 same interface?
because i ask about 2.9 and you wrote 2.8 ? i assume its same interface

Comment: Hello :). Yes, 2.8+ versions all share the same 'new' UI.

Comment: Thanks for the help